# How do I tell TYPO3 what it's URL is when using a reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, typo3, reverse-proxy, typo3-7.6.x

I have:

- A url www.my-website.com
- A machine running TYPO3 with some hostname like typo3-website.my.internal.domain.com
- A machine running Nginx which uses proxy_pass to send requests from www.my-website.com to typo3-website.my.internal.domain.com
- A DNS A record for www.my-website.com pointing to the reverse-proxy machine.

When a backend user is working in the Page module, and they do right-click 'Show' on a page, it tries to open the page at the hostname of the machine TYPO3 is running on.

I want it to open the page under the actual website URL instead.

What setting do I need to change to make this work?

Things I have already tried which did not help:

- Setting the trusted hosts pattern
- 'reverseProxyIP' => '*'
- 'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'last'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create a [domain record](https://wiki.typo3.org/Multidomain#STEP_2_-_Creating_the_domain_records). That partially fixed it.

This still leaves problems where images use the wrong URL in the backend.

This means, that, for example, the little dotted lines in the page tree module do not display.

To fix that, I used a clue from [this forum thread](https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/m/749438/). I needed to set the HTTP_HOST variable to my domain and send it to PHP fpm:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    include ${pkgs.nginx}/conf/fastcgi.conf;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/phpfpm/default.sock;
    # Assorted fastcgi_blah
    fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST "www.my-domain.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get TYPO to see the request as a request for a specific domain, you may want to use the following on your proxy block:

```
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
```

Comment: This won't have any effect, because this is the default behaviour anyway.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to take that out of my configs then.